# How Can i use Deepin in Lubuntu / Xubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, themes

I'm now using the Deepin Desktop Environment at Ubuntu 18.04. But now I want to use Lubuntu!

Can I use Deepin in Lubuntu / Xubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

> Can i use Deepin in Lubuntu / Xubuntu??

Short answer:yes. In reality Lubuntu, Xubuntu, and other flavors all have same Ubuntu base underneath, so there's virtually no difference if you install DDE on Ubuntu 18.04 or  Lubuntu 18.04 or Xubuntu 18.04.

OMGUbuntu, one of the major blogs regarding Ubuntu and related software, provides a [tutorial for most recent release - 18.04 - on how to install Deepin Desktop Environment 15.6](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/how-to-install-deepin-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-18-04). It's applicable to any flavor of Ubuntu. There's just 3 steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
sudo apt install dde dde-file-manager
sudo apt install deepin-gtk-theme
```

There's also a choice between keeping the GDM greeter or using Lightdm, and  I'd recommend Lightdm if you want actual Deepin look for login screen.

Note that PPA is maintained by community members, meaning the PPA isn't officially supported by Deepin developers. Personally, I'd recommend installing actual Deepin OS on your machine: besides official support and updates, the OS itself is designed to work nicely with the desktop environment. To quote from the [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~leaeasy/+archive/ubuntu/dde), "[T]he dde depends on qt version above than 5.6. If you want to install dde, please upgrade to 17.04 or above." so **versions of Ubuntu prior to 17.04 aren't supported**.